# Windows 10: can't drop files into the icon of a shared folder (but it works when I open it)

Tags: windows-10, file-sharing, shared-folders

Dropping files into a close shared folder doesn't work

[image: Windows 10: Can't drop files into a shared folder]

(The folder has been created by another user (userB) connected to the same wifi network, I can open it and see the files of userB)

*When I open this folder, I can drop files into it*.

Any idea how to enable the dragging on this shared folder (when it's closed)?

(the problem occur on a fresh install of windows running Windows 10 version 1903. The shared folder has been created on another computer running on Windows 10 ver. 1809)

Comment: What type of computer is hosting this shared folder? Were you previously able to drag and drop files to this folder on an earlier version of Windows?

Comment: @user1574981 the problem occur on a fresh install of windows. The shared folder has been created on another computer running  Windows 10.

Comment: Take a look at permissions. You almost certainly have read-only access, and not write. Have you tried copying a file on the command line?

Comment: @Mawg but just to be sure: you are aware that when I click on the shared folder, I can drop files on it (or edit anything inside)?

Comment: Then I don't understand the problem; sorry to be so dumb. Question title "`Windows 10: can't drop files into a shared folder`", OP comment "`when I click on the shared folder, I can drop files on it (or edit anything inside)?`"

Comment: @Mawg my bad, I edited the title, the problem only occur when the folder is closed (cf the printscreen)

Comment: Aha! The penny drops :-)  just curious - did you try a command line copy?

Comment: @Mawg Yes, copying using the command line works

Comment: Ok, that helps us narrow it down. Perhaps the desktop icon is `.LNK` file to which you do not have write access, and when you click it, it opens a folder to which you do have write access? Check your access rights to the desktop icon

Comment: thanks for your endurance @Mawg ! The problem is the same  for both, the main folder and the shortcut folder.